# How to find a string from a specific word to other word using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following string and I'm trying to display the information from specific start word to specific end word:

```
Protocolo de medición
\r\n\r\nEnsayador disruptivo
\r\nDPA 75C Versión:  1.07
\r\nNúmero de serie: 1101908010
\r\n11/02/2022 02:15\r\n_____________________________
\r\n\r\nInformación sobre el ensayo
\r\n\r\nNombre de protocolo:        .......................
\r\nNúmero de muestra:      0569.1
\r\nMedición según norma:       ASTM D1816:2004 2mm
\r\nForma de electrodos:        Forma de seta
\r\nDistancia entre electrodos:         2 mm
\r\nFrec. del ensayo:   60 Hz\r\n\r\n_____________________________
\r\n\r\nConfig. según norma 
\r\n\r\nDiámetro de los electrodos:     36  mm\r\n\r\n_____________________________
\r\n\r\nValores de medición
\r\n\r\nTemperatura:        20 °C
\r\n\r\nMedición 1:         60.6  kV
\r\nMedición 2:         72.7  kV\r\nMedición 3:         >75.0  kV
\r\nMedición 4:         54.7  kV\r\nMedición 5:         66.4  kV
\r\n\r\nValor medio:                65.9  kV
\r\nDesviación estándar:            8.4  kV
\r\nDesviación estándar/val. medio: 12.8  %
\r\n\r\n\r\nEnsayo correctamente realiz.
\r\n\r\n\r\nEnsayo ejecutado por:   .......................
```

The code should find the string line

```
\r\nNúmero de muestra:      0569.1 \r\
```

Final result should be

```
0569.1
```

I tried this code only display the word searched

```
@article.description.match(/Número de muestra:\b/)
```

I tried this code and works but i need to count the number from and to

```
<%=  @article.description.slice(249..260) %>
```

What i want is write the FROM WORD - TO WORD string without typing the index word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string you are looking to capture always has a line end character after it at some point you can do:

```
data = @article.description.match(/Número de muestra:*(.*)$/)
```

returns a Match object like:

```
#<MatchData "Número de muestra:      0569.1" 1:"0569.1">
```

you can then access the match with

```
data[1]
# => "0569.1"
```

The Match object stores the matching string in `data[0]` and the first capture is in `data[1]`. In the regexp we are using the `.*` matches the spaces after the string `Número de muestra:`. The `(.*)` matches any characters after the spaces. The `$` matches the end of line character. Anything that matches what is between the parens `()` gets stored as matches in the Match object.